# Unicode encode error

Tags: python, python-3.3

I have written a Python 3.3 program in Ubuntu that works fine. However, when I run it in windows, I get Unicode encode errors. The line it complains about is:

```
if minor:
    print (textwrap.fill('{}: {}'.format(minor,MINOR[minor])),"\n")
```

but I cannot see why it would work under Ubuntu and not Windows. Which character won't windows like? I can't see anything wrong with it.

[image: error pic]

Comment: the complete stacktrace would be helpfull here.

Comment: Pic uploaded to main question

Comment: The problem is probably the encoding of the *terminal*. In linux it is usually utf-8, on windows it's probably latin-1 or cp1252.

Comment: What do you expect this function to print? It tries to print a string containing a character that's invalid in UTF-8 and latin-1 (but valid in cp-1252.)

Answer (score 1):

As it turned out, the problem was in the csv file that was loaded into the 'minor' constant (in this case, dictionary). The problem was where I had copied the txt from was using some weird version of the apostrophe character instead of what it would usually use, so I ran a replace through notepad++ and fixed it.

Comment: Open the file in Notepad++ again and re-save it as a UTF-8 file. Then you'll be able to use all kinds of weird symbols!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem i solved it in the following way :
First decode the string (say string 1) then perform further operations :

```
  string_decoded= (string1.decode('latin_1'))
```